Override Tika default mimetype for Transport MPEG Transport Stream (TS) files
We have Tika detecting MPEG Transport Stream *.ts files as application/octet-stream
This is due to tika-mimetypes.xml not associating the video/m2pt to a *.ts file.
When I attempt to override this entry with a custom-mimetype.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <!-- https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml
    Add file type to the defined mp2t mime.
    Auto loaded since it is in org/apache/tika/mime directory.
    -->
    <mime-info>
        <mime-type type="video/MP2T">
            <_comment>MediaLive Transport Stream Segment</_comment>
            <alias type="video/mp2t"/>
            <glob pattern="*.ts"/>
            <magic priority="1">
                <match value="47" offset="0"/>
            </magic>
        </mime-type>
    </mime-info>
</properties>


and load using a custom-tika-config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <mimeTypeRepository>
        <load path="config/custom-mimetypes.xml"/>
    </mimeTypeRepository>
</properties>

Test:
    @Test
    void whenTikaConfig_givenTikaConfig_thenParse() {
        String filename = "src/test/resources/quarkusTest/crossDomain/transport-stream-test-001.ts";
        TikaConfig tikaConfig = null;
        try {
            tikaConfig = new TikaConfig(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/config/custom-tika-config.xml"));
            tikaConfig.getMediaTypeRegistry().getTypes().forEach(mime -> log.debug(mime.getType()));
            // Create Tika instance with custom config
            Tika tika = new Tika(tikaConfig);

            // Prepare metadata and handler
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

            try (InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
                // Detect MIME type
                String mimeType = tika.detect(stream, metadata);
                log.info("Detected MIME type: {}", mimeType);
                // Output metadata
                for (String name : metadata.names()) {
                    log.info("{}: {}", name, metadata.get(name));
                }
            }
        } catch (TikaException | IOException | SAXException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


and still defaults to: Detected MIME type: application/octet-stream and it is not apparent the custom mimetypes where loaded.
The only way for sure to load the custom mimetypes is to add the system property tika.custom-mimetypes used in MimeTypesFactory.
The source file is from MediaLive HLS S3 ts file segment.
